# Xcode Crash Log: "NO_CRASH_STACK + 0"

Tags: xcode, crash-reports

In Xcode > Organizer > Crashes I see a crash with note "NO_CRASH_STACK + 0".

What does this mean and why does it happen that a crash stack is not available?

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better to check the source code or third party source there is exit() function call. exit() doesn't make crash log. I think calling exit() function may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you find the crash stack:

[image]

On the left, right click the crash report and choose Show in Finder. That reveals an .xccrashpoint document package. Embedded with that there is one or more related crash reports. To see them, control click in the Finder and choose Show Package Contents.